# WordPress 4.5.3 - Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, referenceerror

I got an error in Google console on my [website](https://www.followmytrack.net)

> (index):878 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined(anonymous function) @ (index):878
>   jquery-migrate.min.js:2 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1

When click on the error, i got this : jQuery(window).ready(function($) {

I identify the wp_customize_support_script function in my theme.php but i don't know how i can fix it.

Do you have some idea about my problem ? Thank you

Comment: I did not see where you have included `jQuery` core library. Also you need to revise `jQuery(window).ready(function($) { })`. `$` is reserved word for jQuery untill you release the lock from it using [$.noConflict()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/).

Answer (score 0):

I think the errors are related to the '$' that Rohit416 referred to. It looks like these are embedded in the theme so I would say that you may want to update your theme if it isn't on the latest version.

It looks like your site is using a premium theme called Flavio. If you purchased this from Themeforest you can use the following plugin to make the update: https://github.com/envato/wp-envato-market